# "Combining" a CCSprite into a CCLabelTTF

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a game shop in which players can purchase items. I have a `CCLabelTTF` that outputs the price of an item, and a `CCSprite` right next to it that is an image of a coin (the currency). Since the price of the items changes as the user obtains more items, the labels text begins to overlap the coin `CCSprite` that is right next to the label. I'm trying to make it so that the coin `CCSprite` is positioned based on the labels position. Is there a better way to do this than adding the CCSprite as a child to CCLabelTTF? Such as containing the `CCSprite` in the `CCLabelTTF`?

Right now I have this:

```
coinIcon = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"coin.png"];
[coinIcon setScale:0.3];
priceLabel.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.Lf", price];
[priceLabel addChild:coinIcon];
```

I was also trying to setPositionInPoints, but whenever I set a position `coin` no longer appeared on screen. This is the main problem I've been having using this method. It will work fine without setting a position, but I need the coin to be to the left of `priceLabel`. And when I try to set a position and run the app, it doesn't show up on screen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a CCNode as container , like so:

```
// CCSprite and CCLabelTTF are by default anchored (.5,.5)
// so make label same height as coin and it will line dead-center
// to the coin's vertical apex

float offsetInPoints = 8.f;
float labelWidthInPoints = 80.f;
CCNode* priceNode = [CCNode node];
coinIcon = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"coin.png"];
[coinIcon setScale:0.3];
priceLabel.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.Lf", price];
priceLabel.horizontalAlignment=CCTextAlignmentLeft;
priceLabel.dimensions=CGSizeMake(labelWidthInPoints,coinIcon.contentSizeInPoints.height);
[priceNode addChild:coinIcon];
[priceNode addChild:priceLabel];
priceLabel.positionInPoints = ccpAdd(coinIcon.positionInPoints, 
   ccp(coinIcon.contentSizeInPoints.width+offsetInPoints,coinIcon.position.y));
```

that will place the price label at a constant offsetInPoints to the right of the coin, whatever the price ends up to be.

not tested, coded from memory

Comment: Thankyou @YvesLeBorg for the same height on CCLabelTTF tip for alignment